# How to search for Server Exchange or Server Authentication type certificates installed on host computer using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, ssl-certificate, powershell-2.0, certificate-store

I'm trying to choose a certificate from the computer certificate store `LocalMachine\My` that serves for Server Exchange or Authentication (I'm unsure regarding the exact nomenclature) purposes. I know there are filters to return only certificates of a certain type, as such:

```bsh
    PS> Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My -codesigning
```

and what I want is to do something like:

```
    PS> Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My -exchange
```

Which fails in `PowerShell`.

If such a filter keyword doesn't exists, can some venture a way to do it, or at least how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of certs with server authentication you can filter by the enhanced key usage properties:

```
dir cert:\localmachine\my | ? {
    $_.Extensions | % { 
        $_.EnhancedKeyUsages | ? {
            $_.FriendlyName -eq "Server Authentication"}}}
```

Comment: The FriendlyName property doesn't relate to Server Authentication necessarily, though.

Comment: @rae1n Not sure what you mean. This code will list all certificates that have the [Server Authentication extension](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1.html).

Comment: @rae1n I think you are confusing the FriendlyName property in this code with another friendly name in the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each certificate properties in this way:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | fl *
```

then you can filter by property, in this case filtering by name of issuer:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | where-object { $_.issuer -match "servername" }
```

Comment: No, the issuer does not specify whether the certificate was created for Server Authentication purposes or not, it just displays the same of the Certificate Authority that issued the certificate. I search through the properties of a certificate and couldn't find one that related to its purpose.